# binding checkbox with nested array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with handling checkbox using react, what I want is the state should reflect what condition of the checkbox, and in the end I want to have `[id-1, id-2, id-3]` to save to the backend. But my demo seems broken, I think I miss one condition, but I can't tell what's my problem.

**https://codesandbox.io/s/kpw23v4xv**

```
handleCheckboxChange = (device_id) => {
    const upateStatOfZoneCameraMenu = () => {
      this.setState({
        zones: [...this.state.zones.slice(0, this.state.selectedTab), {
          ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedTab],
          cameras: [
            ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedTab].cameras.map(
              o => ({
                ...o,
                checked: this.state.selectedCameras.find(o2 => o2 === o.device_id) || o.device_id === device_id
              })
            )
          ]
        }, ...this.state.zones.slice(this.state.selectedTab + 1)]
      })
    }

    const updatedSelectedCamera = this.state.selectedCameras.find(obj => obj === device_id)

    if (!updatedSelectedCamera) {
      this.setState({
        selectedCameras: [...this.state.selectedCameras, device_id]
      }, () => {
        upateStatOfZoneCameraMenu()
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        selectedCameras: this.state.selectedCameras.filter(obj => obj !== device_id)
      }, () => {
        upateStatOfZoneCameraMenu()
      })
    }   
  }
```

I think the problem is at line 52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your logic was in setting the `checked` state of your camera.

I have changed the existing code to:

```
checked: this.state.selectedCameras.find(o2 => o2 === o.device_id) !==undefined
```

There were also warnings in your code about keys not being present in elements you create iteratively, which I fixed in App component by adding a key to the divs rendered by the map methods.

There was another warning for changing an uncontrolled component to a controlled component, which was fixed when I introduced the `checked` field in the initial state of your cameras and set it to false.

The detailed code can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2z5o6y3x9p).

Comment: nice catch!! didn't know find return undefined instead of false

Comment: I don't understand why you validated this answer instead of mine because I pointed several misconception of the React philosophy and a proper way to test. This answer works but is not the proper way. Anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your sandbox to provide you a working version: https://codesandbox.io/s/k5ml50ky13

Several problems you had:

1. Prefer to only update your state once instead of several times
2. Your condition on the `checked` property was unclear so I rewrote in order to only verify if the current camera is checked

Basically I just changed the function `handleCheckboxChange`:

```
handleCheckboxChange = (device_id) => {
  const updatedSelectedCamera = this.state.selectedCameras.find(obj => obj === device_id);
  const selectedCameras = updatedSelectedCamera ? this.state.selectedCameras.filter(obj => obj !== device_id) : [...this.state.selectedCameras, device_id];

  this.setState({
    selectedCameras,
    zones: [
      ...this.state.zones.slice(0, this.state.selectedTab),
      {
        ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedTab],
        cameras: [
          ...this.state.zones[this.state.selectedTab].cameras.map(
            o => ({
              ...o,
              checked: selectedCameras.includes(o.device_id),
            })
          )
        ]
      },
      ...this.state.zones.slice(this.state.selectedTab + 1)
    ],
  });
}
```

Hope it helps.